# Having a hard time with Nhibernate Sessions in the context of a Controller and Repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I trying to build an ASP.NET MVC application using Nhibernate and Structuremap along with the Repository pattern.

Through my initial approach to this project and the subsequent reading, I was wanting to keep the Nhibernate Session confined to the Repositories, and the Repositories to the Controller.  But at the same time, in regards to transactions, I wanted to keep this separated from the repository methods (i.e. I just wanted to call session.Save()).

But It almost seems required that the Controller know about the session so that I can perform any transaction setup on the session before any Controller action, and any persistence to the database after the action using something like (i.e. the ActionFilterAttribute methods BeforeExecution or AfterExecuted, or BeginRequest/EndRequest events in the MvcApplication.

So in my mind I am having to give the current NHibernate Session to the Controller as well as the Repository, just so I can act on the Session when certain actions/results occur on the controller.

Is this the only way I can go about this?

I have read Ayende's blogs, and an assortment of different ways to go about this, but in the case of using the repository pattern, this almost seems like a must. I was hoping to be able to make the Nhibernate / StructureMap setup to the most pluggable way possible so with the exception of defining FluentNhibernate configuration for a specific project, there would be very minimal wiring for adding it to another MVC project.

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to why the Controller needs the session in this case - are you saying you just want the controller to be able to establish the transaction scope?

Answer (score 0):

That's ok. You'll need to open your session on your request begin and close it on your request end.